# Convert dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-conversion

Let's say that I have a dataframe like below:

```
id    point      name
1      654        x
2       22        y
3       13        z
4      5463       z
5      1565       z
6       12        x
7      766        y
```

I am looking  for a solution  that could convert
my data frame into list like below:

```
list <- c( x(654,12), y(22,766), z(13,5463,1565))
```

Do you have any idea ? I will be grateful  for any help.
Thanks All !

Comment: `split(df$point, df$name)` ?

Comment: Simply and  itworks, thanks !